# How to get an product limit in a category using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sample data:

```
products (id, name, category_id)
(1, 'Test 1', 1)
(2, 'Test 2', 1)
(3, 'Test 3', 1)
(4, 'Test 4', 2)
(5, 'Test 5', 2)
(6, 'Test 6', 2)
(7, 'Test 7', 3)
```

How to ideas, get 2 product in 1 category_id
ex:

```
(1, 'Test 1', 1)
(2, 'Test 2', 1)
(4, 'Test 4', 2)
(5, 'Test 5', 2)
(7, 'Test 7', 3)
```

Comment: This is just a slight variation on one of the most frequently repeated duplicated question on all of SO - "greatest n per group". Please search for similar questions, have a go yourself and then show what you've tried.

Comment: Try in your SQL to GROUP BY category_id

Comment: Look at the first question in the "Related" sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT id, name, category_id
FROM   products p
WHERE 
(
   SELECT count(*) 
   FROM   products f
   WHERE  f.category_id = p.category_id AND
          f.id <= p.id
) <= 2;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b52c/1)